# Reading multiple lines of input

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

What command / function can I use to read the second line in the input section so the 4 and 6 I know I'll have to fix the output to output two digits. I just need helping figuring out how to read the second line of input any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

segment .data 
    NEWLINE db 0xa, 0xd
    LENGTH equ $-NEWLINE

   msg1 db "Enter a digit "
   len1 equ $- msg1 
  

   msg2 db "Please enter a second digit "
   len2 equ $- msg2 

   msg3 db "The sum is: "
   len3 equ $- msg3

segment .bss
   INPT resd 1
   num1 resb 2 
   num2 resb 2 
   res resb 1    

section .text
   global _start    ;must be declared for using gcc
    
_start:             ;tell linker entry point
   mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg1         
   mov edx, len1 
   int 0x80  
   
   mov eax, SYS_READ 
   mov ebx, STDIN  
   mov ecx, num1 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80

   mov eax, SYS_WRITE          
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, num1        
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80 
    
   mov eax, 0x4
   mov ebx, 0x1
   mov ecx, NEWLINE
   mov edx, LENGTH
   int 0x80 

   mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg2          
   mov edx, len2         
   int 0x80

   mov eax, SYS_READ  
   mov ebx, STDIN  
   mov ecx, num2 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80   
   
   mov eax, SYS_WRITE          
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, num2        
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80
   
   mov eax, 0x4
   mov ebx, 0x1
   mov ecx, NEWLINE
   mov edx, LENGTH
   int 0x80 

   mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg3          
   mov edx, len3         
   int 0x80

   ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
   ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
    
   mov eax, [num1] 
   sub eax, '0'
    
   mov ebx, [num2]
   sub ebx, '0'

   ; add eax and ebx
   add eax, ebx
   ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
   add eax, '0'

   ; storing the sum in memory location res
   mov [res], eax

   ; print the sum 
   mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
   mov ebx, STDOUT
   mov ecx, res         
   mov edx, 1        
   int 0x80

exit:    
   
   mov eax, SYS_EXIT   
   xor ebx, ebx 
   int 0x80
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KydKR.png)

Comment: Do you understand what the code by SYS_READ does?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could use the same command for mulilply lines.